# Moving javascript from view to javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have several views that contain this same javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $("#addAnother").click(function () {
        $.get('/QuestionGroup/QuestionEntryRow', function (template) {
            $("#questionEditor").append(template);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I decided to move this logic to a javascript file.  So here what I did.

On my view I added a data-attr.

```
        <a method="get" action="@Url.Action("QuestionEntryRow", "QuestionGroup")" href="#">Add another</a>
```

In the javascript file I added the following code.

```
  var insertRow = function () {
      var $a = $(this);

      var options = {
          url: $a.attr("action"),
          type: $a.attr("method")
      };

      $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
          var $target = $($a.attr("data-cban-target"));
          $target.append(data);
      });

      return false
  };

  $("a[data-cban-a]").click(insertRow);
```

When the user click the link "Add another".  The javascript is not getting executed.

Target

```
<ul data-cureurban-target="questionEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
</ul>
```

Here the controller logic

```
public ActionResult QuestionEntryRow()
{
    ViewBag.QuestionID = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionID", "QuestionDesc");

    return PartialView("_QuestionEntryEditor");
}
```

Comment: If the javascript file reference is in the head of the document you are trying to assign the click handler before the `a` element exists.

Comment: How can I make this document ready

Comment: The `$(function() { });` _is_ a document ready handler.

Comment: The line url: $a.attr("action") should throw an error. There is no attribute named "action" on the hyperlink. Again no attribute has been specified for "data-cban-target".

Comment: This is the url  :  data-cban-a="@Url.Action("QuestionEntryRow", "QuestionGroup")".   The view page source would like like this data-cureurban-a="/QuestionGroup/QuestionEntryRow"

Comment: At @Jasen, the problem is when they have moved the code they have taken it out of $(function() { });

Comment: where you are specifying   "data-cban-a" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for your .js file:

```
var insertRow = function () {
  var $a = $(this);

  var options = {
      url: $a.attr("action"),
      type: $a.attr("method")
  };

  $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
      var $target = $($a.attr("data-cban-target"));
      $target.append(data);
  });

  return false
};

$(document).ready(){
    $("a[data-cban-a]").click(insertRow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon P.  This is still not working.  I did change the view to use this logic  <a method="get" action="@Url.Action("QuestionEntryRow", "QuestionGroup")" href="#">

Comment: @RThompson is that selector correct `$("a[data-cban-a]")`? Does it match anything on the page?

Comment: Can you provide more info other than "not working"? Any error messages etc? What debugging have you performed? Based on Jasens' comment you are missing the `action` and `method` attributes. Where are you expecting them to come from.

Comment: When I place my cursor over the Add another it is  showing this controller action http://localhost:60856/QuestionGroup/Create#.   I did fix the problem with the "action".  <a method="get" action="@Url.Action("QuestionEntryRow", "QuestionGroup")" href="#">Add another</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `javascript:void(0)` in href of anchor tag.

```
<a method="get" action="@Url.Action("QuestionEntryRow", "QuestionGroup")" href="javascript:void(0)">Add another</a>
```

Refer this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0) post for more details

Comment: When  I click the link "Add another" nothing is happening.  When I place the cursor over the link I do see the "javascript:void(0)".

Comment: I made the following changes.  First I changed the view to this         <a data-cureurban-ajax="true" method="get" action="@Url.Action("QuestionEntryRow", "QuestionGroup")" href="javascript:void(0)">Add another</a>.    Then I change the .js to this $("a[data-cureurban-ajax='true']").click(insertRow).  When clicking nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Default *event propogation* for (a)anchor tag needs to be stopped.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#addAnother").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get('/QuestionGroup/QuestionEntryRow', function (template) {
            $("#questionEditor").append(template);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```